# SSRS and Sharepoint 2007 Reportviewer Webpart connectivity issue

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2007, reportingservices-2005

I have a problem trying to display my SSRS reports in a Report Viewer webpart. In the report server I can see them without any problems.
However when I try to show them in a Sharepoint webpart I get the following error:

```
Error al procesar el informe. (rsProcessingAborted)
Error de ejecución de consulta para el conjunto de datos 'DimEstadoEstado'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Either the user, , does not have access to the SeguridadSocialBI database, or the database does not exist.
```

Translated it'd be something like

```
Error processing the report. (rsProcessingAborted)
Execution error for dataset 'DimEstadoEstado' (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Either the user, , does not have access to the SeguridadSocialBI database, or the database does not exist.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pleas note there's no user showed in the error, no matters if I'm logged into Sharepoint, perhaps it's an authentication issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set credentials for data source to access the report. Set User Name and Password and check windows authentication for rdl on sharepoint.